# sockaddr_storage size of 128 bytes

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I was just wondering why exactly the sockaddr_storage was 128 bytes. I understand it has to be at least what 28 bytes for IPv6 but this seems a little excessive to have like 100 extra bytes larger than sockaddr_in6. Is this just to future proof the storage struct or is there a reason that its needed right now?

Comment: How big is a `struct sockaddr_atmsvc`? I don't know either, but I bet its bigger than 28 bytes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will find an answer to your questions in §3.10 of [rfc 2553](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2553.txt) and in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345109/why-sockaddr-storage-structure-defined-as-the-way-it-is-defined).

The reason is a combination of *should at least hold ip6 and other protocols data* and *64-bit aligned* for efficiency.

From the relevant part of the RFC:

> One simple addition to the sockets API that can help application
>   writers is the "struct sockaddr_storage". This data structure can
>   simplify writing code portable across multiple address families and
>   platforms.  This data structure is designed with the following goals.
>
> ```
>   - It has a large enough implementation specific maximum size to
>     store the desired set of protocol specific socket address data
>     structures. Specifically, it is at least large enough to
>     accommodate sockaddr_in and sockaddr_in6 and possibly other
>     protocol specific socket addresses too.
>   - It is aligned at an appropriate boundary so protocol specific
>     socket address data structure pointers can be cast to it and
>     access their fields without alignment problems. (e.g. pointers
>     to sockaddr_in6 and/or sockaddr_in can be cast to it and access
>     fields without alignment problems).
>   - It has the initial field(s) isomorphic to the fields of the
>     "struct sockaddr" data structure on that implementation which
>     can be used as a discriminants for deriving the protocol in use.
>     These initial field(s) would on most implementations either be a
>     single field of type "sa_family_t" (isomorphic to sa_family
>     field, 16 bits) or two fields of type uint8_t and sa_family_t
>     respectively, (isomorphic to sa_len and sa_family_t, 8 bits
>     each).
> ```

Answer (score 3):

There might be systems which want to be able to fit a [`struct sockaddr_un`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/sys/un.h.html) in this structure as well. The latter has a system dependent path length of about 100 to 110 characters. And 128 is a beautifully even number.